# How to make nested MaterialTopTabNavigator capture swipe gesture from parent StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to do something very close to Instagram and ran into some trouble with the posts section of another users profile screen.

My current set up:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={gestureResponseDistance: {horizontal: SCREEN_WIDTH}}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
<Stack.Navigator/>
```

Inside Profile I have:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
...
<Tab.Navigator>
     <Tab.Screen name="Posts" component={Posts} />
     <Tab.Screen name="Tags" component={Tags} />
     <Tab.Screen name="Locations" component={Locations} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

My problem is when I swipe right inside the `MaterialTopTabNavigator`, the parent `StackNavigator` captures it because of the `gestureResponseDistance` resulting in the whole screen swiping not the `TabNavigator`.

I can't disable the gesture for the screen because if the user swipes anywhere outside the `TabNavigator` they should be able to go back.

How can I solve that? Thanks.